# How to make an audio CD for a(n emulated) Playstation?

Tags: emulation, sony-playstation, audio, cd-rom

I can't manage to burn a working audio CD-R for my (both emulated and non-emulated) PlayStation.

I'd like to get instructions on how to do it in a GNU/Linux environment (also without using a real CD-R), if possible.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are asking how to use modern tools on a modern computer to feed a modern (emulation) software?

Comment: Both a modern emulation software and a real PlayStation, yes.

Comment: A real PlayStation will play any audio CD. It has no specific requirements or quirks. So for that the question is just: how do I burn an audio CD?

Comment: CDRoms burned without the extra conversion described below don't work on my PlayStation. Don't know what to say, I agree with you in saying standard procedure worked correctly 15 years ago.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck … and do they work in any other CD player? I’m willing to wager not.

Comment: @Tommy I don't have compact disc players other than PlayStation readily available at this moment.

Comment: Surely, since you have a disc burner, you can rip back the CD in the very same drive.

Comment: I never said I have a disc burner readily available, too.

Comment: If you don't have a burner, how can you know the normal procedure doesn't work with a physical PlayStation (while working with everything else)?

Comment: All IDE slots are full so I asked a friend to bring a laptop with a burner. We had tea with biscuits and played a couple games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### One-step procedure (command line)

Since no tool to do what I'm asking (audio cdr in `.bin` + `.cue` format from input media source) seemed to exist I have written one myself, `mkaudiocdrimg`([`AUR`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mkaudiocdrimg)).

```
$ mkaudiocdrimg songA.mp3 songB.mp3 --image-name track_collection1
```

Also as a Python module it can be easily used by other applications as a library.

#### Multi-step manual graphical procedure

- Create an audio cdrom `image.bin/image.cue` pair using `brasero`;

[image]

- replace the `MOTOROLA` value with `BINARY` in the `FILE` cue command in `image.cue`.

[image]

The reason you need to do this is because `duckstation-qt` (`pcsxr` is not even able to load anything different than a videogame image)
[only supports `BINARY` as value for `FILE`](https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation/blob/bdde3c/src/util/cue_parser.cpp#L221-L225)
and `brasero`
[only produces big-endian images](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/brasero/-/blob/fb08c2/plugins/audio2cue/burn-audio2cue.c#L425),
so without passing for a sound ripper such as `sound-juicer` you will get distorted audio when playing the image in the emulator. More in general, valid values for `FILE` command should be these listed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ccd2cue/manual/html_node/FILE-_0028CUE-Command_0029.html).

So now

- mount `image.cue` using `cdemu`:

```
    $ cdemu load 0 image.cue
```

- write the virtual CDROM to `image2.bin/image2.cue` using the *"duplicate"* function of `sound-juicer`; be sure to select "Cue image" as file format.

[image]

[image]

- Finally,
- if you're using an emulator, just load `image2.cue` as the disc file;
- if you're using a real playstation, burn `image2.cue` at slowest speed on a cdrom.

I can confirm the same procedure works for CDRoms to be played on Kronos emulator or on a real Sega Saturn.

##### References

Helpful resources in writing the program:

- this Arch forums [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144388);
- [audio streaming - How do I change the bit depth in FFmpeg? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/547929/how-do-i-change-the-bit-depth-in-ffmpeg);
- [Command Line Arguments · stenzek/duckstation Wiki](https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141111/discussion-on-answer-by-scrooge-mcduck-how-to-make-an-audio-cd-for-an-emulated).